# Seekbar changing values of int

Tags: android, int, android-seekbar

I have a seekbar and would like to set it up so that it will change the int value of my doBrightness method I have so that when you slide the seekbar, it will change the brightness of the image.

here is the start of the doBrightness method, I would like to change the values of the int from the seekbar:

How would I be able to achieve this?

```
public Bitmap doBrightness(Bitmap src, int value) {
           .....................
  }
```

here is the seekbar I have set up:

```
sb = (SeekBar)v.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);

    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            sb.setProgress(0);
            sb.setMax(100);

            //Change the int value of the doBrightness from here?
        }
    });
```

Comment: What are the max and min values for second argument in `doBrightness` method signature?

Comment: @bhargavg Adjusting brightness

Answer (score 0):

```
sb = (SeekBar)v.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
sb.setProgress(0);
sb.setMax(100);

sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //doBrightness change here
    }
});
```

Comment: How can I change the value of dobrightness from the progress of the seekbar? so when I slide it half way, seekbar progress will = 50 so then the doBrightness int will = 50 as well?

Comment: use progress variable of onProgressChanged method

Comment: I have tried doBrightness(bitmap1, progress); but that doesn't do anything.